Honeywell’s 5A (SA?) and PP codes are nowhere to be explained
My Honeywell Smart Dehumidifier (TP50AWKN) 32 pint started cycling two messages on the screen, while continuing working. I’ve searched everywhere for these codes but they don’t seem to be documented, see images. Tried cleaning the filter, plug unplug etc but no luck. What are they?



https://honeywellaircomfort.com/pages/portable-dehumidifier-faqs says SA code is a pairing code: "Press the timer button 6 times and the codes will disappear."  No idea about PP.  Try the timer button and see if the PP goes away too.

Also here us the version of the manual having the WiFi setup info. THe manual I got when I purchased did not include these instructions.
https://www.honeywellstore.com/store/images/pdf/honeywell-tp-smart-app-series-dehumidifier-manual.pdf

The PP code comes on and goes away with startup mode. Its an indicator of the pump feature available in this unit.
